# Warning due to semicolon

Tags: ocaml

I run a hello world program below

```
let x=3;

print_string "hello world!";;
```

and got this warning:

```
File "hello.ml", line 1, characters 6-7:
1 | let x=3;
          ^
Warning 10 [non-unit-statement]: this expression should have type unit.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall from the answers to your previous questions that `;` is a sequence operator, not a statement terminator. Your code will therefore be interpreted as:

```
let x = (3; print_string "hello world!")
```

which is equivalent to:

```
let x = print_string "hello world!"
```

Meaning that you're throwing away the `3`, and `x` will have type `unit` because that's what `print_string` returns. You can "fix it", i.e. get rid of the warning, by using the second form above.

Comment: Nice! I think another fix is to use "let x = 3;;" instead of of a single semicolon

Comment: In an OCaml program, at the toplevel everything needs to be a definition. If a definition exists purely for the side effects of its expression, binding to unit (`()`) will cover making it a definition _and_ give you a handy compiler error if your expression does not evaluate to unit.